# How to make an editable DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC to get the right values?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using this plugin, in MVC 4, to get a Editable DropDownList:

http://coffeescripter.com/code/editable-select/

What I did was:
1- include the scripts, under the scripts folder.
2- Add the css part, in the last part of my css file.
3- Add the image to my content folder.
5- Add the function to my partial view.

Function:

```
$(function () {


        $('#lugar').editableselect(
          {
              bg_iframe: true,

              onselect: function (list_item) {
                  alert('list item text: ' + list_item.text());
                  // 'this' is a reference to the instance of editableselect
                  // object, so you have full access to everything there
                  alert('input value: ' + this.text.val());
              },
              case_sensitive: false, // if set to true, the user has to type in an exact
              // match for the item to get highlighted
              items_then_scroll: 10 // if there are more than 10 items, display a scrollbar
          }
        );
        var select = $('#lugar:first');
        var instances = select.editableselectinstances();
        instances[5].addoption('germany, value added programmatically');
    });
```

6- Add the class to my field.

```
<div class="editor-field editableSelect">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lugar)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lugar)
</div>
```

**Problem**
1- I'm getting the list (without the image) but with wrong values in it. I don't know where is it getting those values from.
2- I don't see where I pass the values that I want to the list, Could you guide me in the right way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to display editable select using coffeescript in ASP.NET MVC 4 and twitter bootstrap.

Please see the details below,

In your MVC project, add reference to necessary coffeescript and jquery (I used jquery-1.9.1.js) files.

1. In View, add the following code,

> ```
> <select id="user_name_ddl" class="editable-select"> 
> </select>
> ```

2. Open 'jquery.editable-select.css' in your project and update the correct image location,

> ```
> input.editable-select {
>   background: #FFF url(images/arrow-down.gif) right center no-repeat;
>   padding-right: 13px;
>   cursor:pointer;
> }
> ```

Note: I copied the arrow-down image into an images folder in my MVC project.

3. In your custom .js file (if not, create one) add the following lines of code,

> ```
> $(function () {
>   $('.editable-select').editableSelect({
>     bg_iframe: true,
>     onSelect: function (list_item) {
>       $('#results').html('List item text: ' + list_item.text() + '<br/> \
>         Input value: ' + this.text.val());
>       }
>     });
>     var select = $('.editable-select:first');
>     var instances = select.editableSelectInstances();    
>     if (instances != null
>         && instances != undefined
>         && instances.length > 0) instances[0].addOption("Item 1");
> });
> ```

That's it. Now, you will be able to see an editable select.